# Check if directory exists on Client's PC

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webserver, client

In WinForms VB.NET you can check if a directory exists, like so `If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists()` but how would I do this in ASP.NET. I have tried as above, but it checks on the "Server" and not the end user that is looking at the website from his/her workplace/home. How would I go about getting a folder that exists on the client's side?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why show if the end-user has .Net 4.0 on their PC, you realise the server is running .Net and simply serving up pages as HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this. Accessing local files from webpages is impossible, and for good reason - it would be a major security risk.

Comment: Ahh, ok, not even read only? I just want to see if the client has the latest .net framework, so I wanted to check if `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` folder exists, could you guide me to another way? What about the registry? Thanks

Comment: @user959631: Are you downloading something? Using a Silverlight component? They'll need to do their own checks. But registry access is also impossible. If there's nothing that can do its own check, you could create an ActiveX control, but it would have to be approved and would only work on Internet Explorer.

Comment: you can do it if you have a caspol set up

Comment: @minitech No, I have a program made in .Net Framework 4, and I want to see, on my website, if the current viewer has .Net Framework 4 or no, if not then download the .Net Framework 4.

Comment: @user959631: If you can make your installer automatically download .NET 4, then do so. Otherwise - you're probably out of luck, sorry.

Comment: Ok, I think I'll try making my Setup program download it instead. Thanks

Comment: Just realised that the setup program won't even start if the end user doesn't have .net framework 4, -.- Never mind, lol.

Comment: @user959631: Do you have a custom setup program written? Try the OneClick installer or something like Inno Setup, which don't require .NET and will download them automatically.

Comment: Err, yeah, I'm using a custom installer, that I made, it has to be custom for many reasons, and I have found a way so it's ok. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

minitech is correct.

Keep in mind though that you could do it with the [caspol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb6t8dtz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), Silverlight or an ActiveX running in IE.

If you really need to know if a directory exists with ASP.Net you'l need a workaround. eg a client could download a file (exe, bat, vbs, etc) and execute it to call a web service to tell you. Hardly ideal.

I guess a one click .Net 4 installer and then you can assume everyone has it.